# Is there any editor which can edit 100 MB of file on Windows Operating system?

Tags: windows, text-editors

I need one editor which can edit huge sizes(100 MB to GBs) of log files in windows.

Comment: Do you need to actually edit, or is viewing enough? If you need to edit, is it an option to parse the edits with a script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may have a look at [gVim](http://www.vim.org/download.php).

But i think your question is already [answered here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files)

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean actually *edit* or just view. I can't think of any other use case other than fraud where you'd want to change a log file :-)

For viewing log files, I just use `less` from either [CygWin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or the [GNUWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) suite. Choose the former if you wan every UNIX tool under the sun. Choose the latter if you want to be a bit more selective.

Comment: cool, didn't know about the GnuWin32 suite, I was always using the ancient unix utils http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/ . thanks

Answer (score 2):

I've edited large log files with Notepad++, slow as it was, it didn't crash.

Comment: It's worth noting there's a 64 bit version which in theory should be able to support files larger than 2GB - although in practice it's probably unusable at that scale.

Comment: +1 for Notepad++.  However Josh I don't believe there is a 64 bit version of notepad++.

Answer (score 0):

Try [FirstObject XML Editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm).  You can just ignore the XML features.

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe what's your purpose ?  more then 100mb is too large to edit by a human. Use the sed, perl, or any scripting as the editor is better.

Comment: If I am to change 1 line in a file, I can edit it. No matter how large it is, and I am human (last time I checked).

Answer (score 0):

I believe both the 'vim' and 'emacs' editors handle large files very well (i.e. no slowdown, they don't load the whole file into memory at once).

Both are available for windows, but installation may not be completely straight-forward. If you're familiar with either editor, or know your way around the computer well enough then they may prove useful.

- [vim project page](http://www.vim.org/) - [download page](http://www.vim.org/download.php) (includes win32 binaries - you're after GVim)
- [emacs project page](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs.html) - [pre-complied emacs binaries for windows](http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/windows/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). It is pretty good.

> Notepad++ is a free 
>   source code editor and Notepad replacement that supports several
>   languages. Running in the MS Windows environment, its use is governed
>   by GPL License.

Notepad++ features:

> - Syntax Highlighting and Syntax Folding
> - User Defined Syntax Highlighting and Folding
> - PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expression) Search/Replace
> - Document Map
> - Auto-completion
> - Multi-Document (Tab interface)
> - Multi-View
> - WYSIWYG (Printing)
> - Zoom in and zoom out
> - Multi-Language environment supported
> - Bookmark
> - Macro recording and playback